# python dictionary from a different method causing "missing positional argument" error

Tags: python, function, dictionary, methods

I am making a cli 'rush hour' game in python. The game board is coming from the user's input, and the cars are represented by letters. I parse the board to find each car by adding every unique letter to a dictionary. I am trying to use the dictionary of cars to create the cars (instances of the car class earlier in the code) and calculate size and direction.

With the code I have here in the board class, I am getting the following error: TypeError: create_all_cars_in_this_board() missing 1 required positional argument: 'my_cars_dict'

It seems like the find_all_cars_in_this_board method is working, but the create_all_cars_in_this_board method isn't able to access it.

```
def find_all_cars_in_this_board(self):
    my_cars_dict = {}
    for h in range(self.height):
        for w in range(self.width):
            if self.game_board[h][w].isalpha():
                if self.game_board[h][w] in my_cars_dict:
                    my_cars_dict[self.game_board[h][w]].append((h, w))
                else:
                    my_cars_dict[self.game_board[h][w]] = [(h, w)]
    return my_cars_dict

def create_all_cars_in_this_board(self, my_cars_dict):
    my_cars = []
    for letter in my_cars_dict.keys():
        c = Car(my_cars_dict[letter])
        my_cars.append(c)
        for c in my_cars:
            c.calc_size()
            c.calc_direction()
    return my_cars
```

Comment: We'd need to see how you're calling `create_all_cars_in_this_board`. According to the error though, you're either not passing `my_cars_dict`, or you're calling the method as though it were static.

Comment: You do not show the code where `create_all_cars_in_this_board` is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See 2 working options below.

Which one is the right one for you?

We cant tell since we cant see all the details of your code.

```
class CarSomething:
  def find_all_cars_in_this_board(self):
      my_cars_dict = {}
      for h in range(self.height):
          for w in range(self.width):
              if self.game_board[h][w].isalpha():
                  if self.game_board[h][w] in my_cars_dict:
                      my_cars_dict[self.game_board[h][w]].append((h, w))
                  else:
                      my_cars_dict[self.game_board[h][w]] = [(h, w)]
      return my_cars_dict

  def create_all_cars_in_this_board(self):
      my_cars_dict = self.find_all_cars_in_this_board()
      my_cars = []
      for letter in my_cars_dict.keys():
          c = Car(my_cars_dict[letter])
          my_cars.append(c)
          for c in my_cars:
              c.calc_size()
              c.calc_direction()
      return my_cars

car = CarSomething()
car.create_all_cars_in_this_board()

#---------------------- OR -------------------------

class CarSomething:
  def find_all_cars_in_this_board(self):
      my_cars_dict = {}
      for h in range(self.height):
          for w in range(self.width):
              if self.game_board[h][w].isalpha():
                  if self.game_board[h][w] in my_cars_dict:
                      my_cars_dict[self.game_board[h][w]].append((h, w))
                  else:
                      my_cars_dict[self.game_board[h][w]] = [(h, w)]
      return my_cars_dict

  def create_all_cars_in_this_board(self,my_cars_dict):
      my_cars = []
      for letter in my_cars_dict.keys():
          c = Car(my_cars_dict[letter])
          my_cars.append(c)
          for c in my_cars:
              c.calc_size()
              c.calc_direction()
      return my_cars

car = CarSomething()
my_cars_dict = car.find_all_cars_in_this_board()
car.create_all_cars_in_this_board(my_cars_dict)
```

Comment: the second is the right one

Comment: Great. I hope the issue is solved. Feel free to up vote.